# LibreOffice: See reason for broken images

Tags: libreoffice

I guess most users of libreoffice know the icon for a missing image:

[image: libreoffice-missing-image]

Unfortunately right-click on the icon does not reveal details.

I guess the image is missing because it was not embedded.

How can I reveal the details like the file-path which libreoffice tries to access.

I am using Version 5.1.6.2

Comment: If you open LibreOffice from the terminal, can you see any relevant message?

Comment: Which version and component of LibreOffice is this?

Comment: @DKBose I added version info.

Comment: The reason I asked for the version is that I can't reproduce the issue with LibreOffice version 6.0.4.2. In this version, an inserted image is present even after a couple of reboots without embedding it. I remember in some earlier version (?) that embedding was needed.

Comment: @DKBose both ways (embedding, linking) images work. This is working. If you just link to the image (instead of embedding it), and then the image file gets deleted, then my LibreOffice shows above symbol.  I guess this should be easily reproduced with a more modern version of libreoffice, too. But: I want to have more informations, not just this broken-image-icon: What image does LibreOffice point to?

Answer (score 5):

In the current version of LibreOffice (I used Writer) I inserted a linked image, then renamed the image file.

After that Writer shows an empty frame instead of the image. Right clicking the frame and choosing the properties I get the following in the Image tab where in the Link field I can see the name of the file I linked:

[image: Image Properties dialogue]

Answer (score 4):

You can display **all** images that externally linked and not embedded from **one screen**. First select the *Edit* menu and then choose the *Links…* option to display this screen:

[image: LibreOffice Edit Links.png]